# How can I get the status of non-blocking jobs of gearman submit_multiple_jobs?

Tags: nonblocking, gearman, python-gearman

how can I tell if a background job or a non-blocking request by gearman client is successful or not?

```
while (True):
    jobs = getJobs()
    submitted_requests = gm_client.submit_multiple_jobs(jobs, background = False, wait_until_complete = False)
    # check status in a non-blocking mode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this link](https://pythonhosted.org/gearman/client.html)

here is the snippet

```
completed_requests = gm_client.wait_until_jobs_completed(submitted_requests, poll_timeout=5.0)
for completed_job_request in completed_requests:
    check_request_status(completed_job_request)
```

check_request_status is defined in the link.